# gelfand algebra problem 32

Tags: combinatorics

how many "$($" and "$)$" symbols do you need to completely specify the order of operations in the product
$2*3*4*5*6*\ldots*99*100$ ?

I know there are $99$ terms, but how do I count the parentheses and are there more than one correct answer ?

Comment: Are the periods supposed to be multiply or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: yes, it is the product of numbers from 2 to 100

Answer (score 2):

If we insist on opening and closing parentheses when for all cases other than singleton sequences of natural numbers, the answer is 2*98. Otherwise, the answer is 2*97.

First let's count the number of left parentheses needed to produce an expression that is either enclosed in parentheses such as $(1 \cdot 2)$ or just a number like $4$ .

We can write out a grammar in pseudo-EBNF notation for this. Let `N` be a natural number and `E` refer to a well-formed expression.

```
E := N | '(' E . E ')'
```

So, every expression is either a number, or two expressions interleaved with the sequence of symbols `( . )` .

Let's imagine starting with the singleton sequence `E` and choosing to expand it using the left hand side of the rule or the right hand side of the rule.

You get 1 E for free when you are starting out, so with zero left parentheses you can make a singleton sequence with just a natural number like `72231` .

In general through, if you have an `E`, you have a choice between converting it into exactly one natural number or two `E`'s . If you choose the two `E` route, then the total number of `E`s increases by one, and the number of parentheses increases by one as well.

For instance, here's deriving `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))`

```
         E
     (E  . E)
((E . E) . E)
((E . E) . (E . E))
--skip a few steps here
((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))
```

At every step, there is one more *E or natural number* than left parenthesis.

So, with 2..100, there are 99 numbers total, and therefore 98 left parentheses.

If we don't want to insist on an outermost level of parentheses wrapping the entire expression, then there are only 97 left parentheses.